# Find the conditions on $(a,b,c)$ so that the following integral converges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Find the conditions on $(a,b,c)$ so that the following integral converges:
> $$\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{x^a(\ln x)^b(\ln\ln x)^c}dx$$

For $a=b=c=1$, we have
$$\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{x(\ln x)(\ln\ln x)}dx = \big[\ln\ln\ln x\big]^{\to\infty}_{\to e}= \infty$$
Hence, for this case, the integral diverges.

Taking $t=\ln x$, we get
$$\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{x^a(\ln x)^b(\ln\ln x)^c}dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{(1-a)t}}{t^b (\ln t)^c}dt$$
Now, I don't see any way to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is right, indeed by $x=e^y \implies dx=e^ydy$ we obtain

$$\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{x^a(\ln x)^b(\ln\ln x)^c}dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y^be^{(a-1)y}(\ln y)^c}dy$$

from which we see that for $c\ge 1 $ the integral

$$\int_1^2 \frac{1}{y^be^{(a-1)y}(\ln y)^c}dy$$

diverges.

Therefore we can assume $c<1$ and proceed with the other cases.

Looking at $\infty$, we also need $a\ge 1$. We can easily show that for $a>1$ the integral converges, then we can study the cases with $a=1$ that is

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y^b(\ln y)^{c}}dy$$

Comment: Thanks. But it seems like it's a similar integral that I got to and stuck. Could you help me a bit further, please?

Comment: BTW, the book gives $c<1$. Is it wrong?

Comment: @VIVID Yes of course, sorry I fix that. As $x \to 1^+$ we have $\log (x)=\log (1+y) \sim y$ as $y\to 0^+$ that is convergence for $c<1$. I fix that point.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Excuse me, but may I take your few more minutes, please? I'm really struggling with improper integrals.Does the integral converge when $a>1, b<0, c<1$ and $a=1,b=1,c>0$? Sorry for the late question.

Comment: @VIVID We always need $c<1$ to avoid divergence at $y=1$. Then the integral converges when $a>1$ and $c<1$ for any $b$ and for $a=1$ and $c<1$ for $b>1$. Do you agree with that?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot rigorously prove that for $a>1, b<0, c<1$ the integral converge.

Comment: @VIVID For the case $a>1, b<0, c<1$ we have it suffices to use limit comparison test at $\infty$ with $\int \frac1{e^{\frac{a-1}2y}}dy$. For the case $a=b=1$ and $c \in (0,1)$ we can use limit comparison test with $\int \frac1y dy$.

Comment: $$\lim\frac{e^{\frac{a-1}{2}y}}{e^{\frac{(a-1)y}y^b(\ln y)^c = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{(1-a)y}{2}y^b( \ln y)^c}$$ this limit should be constant for the comparison test, shouldn't it?

Comment: @VIVID Limit comparison test also apply for the extreme cases. See [that](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find where I missed a bracket in that formula :D. Will see that right now

Comment: Yes, got everything now, Thank you very much for being with me till the end!

Comment: @VIVID That's nice, you are very welcome! Bye